# Data template and steady item in ListPicker

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, datatemplate, listpicker

I am wondering if i can create a ListPicker which is combined together from Items taken from Data Template and one item in the bottom that is steady, and is always there.

Here is my code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker 
    x:Name="subjectTeacherListPicker" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllTeachers}"
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="5">

    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                 <Run Text="{Binding TeacherName}"/>
                 <Run Text="{Binding TeacherSurname}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I mean, to the code above i'd like to add one item to the list picker that will be shown in the same way as all the items but will be settled one time and will stay there no matter what. Like for example, "Add new teacher..", that will be viewed even no other item will be shown.

Comment: How about stacking other control (`TextBlock` or `Button` possibly) over the `ListPicker` to display "Add new teacher.." text, and set each control's `Visibility` property properly according to current situation

Comment: hi, could you extend the part of your idea about Visibility? Actually im not sleeping for over 24 hours, so maybe im not catching something simple, but if you can write something more i will be gratefull

Comment: ok, i tried gather my head back, and what i understand is that u suggest to make, let's say, Button not visible before i click the listpicker control and visible when i click it. If this is your idea, its not bad. But still im wondering if there is any other way to do that.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're after. I thought you want "Add new teacher.." button only visible when there is no item in the `ListPicker`. Is that wrong? Or you actually want the button always visible as last/first item of `ListPicker`?

Comment: yes exactly - i meant i want button always visible as last item of ListPicker

Comment: Couldn't you just manually add it to your list of teachers every time the data is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is you cannot bind different object types to an itemSource so you cannot do this using the `ListPicker` control. There is a control that is overlooked alot called `ItemsControl`. This can have items bound to it and it creates a non-scrolling stacked list of the bound objects. Combining this control with a `ScrollViewer` and a `StackPanel` will give the desired results.

[image: 1]

This is scrollable with the button you need on the bottom of the list. it will always be there even when there is no data in the list.

The XAML to make this happen is as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllTeachers}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding TeacherName}"/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding TeacherSurname}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    <Button Content="Add teacher"/>                    
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Replacing your `ListPicker` with the code I provided will give you a really great starting point to finish customizing the `ItemTemplate` to get the desired item look.

If you need the "Add Teacher" to be some other control, such as a `TextBlock`, simply change the control and have it trigger the Add Teacher action.

Hope this helps!

Adam